# Saving event handlers to Redux.Store - is a good idea?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

For example, consider such a structure of components:

```
<Provider>
  <App>
    <LoginForm />
  </App>
</Provider>
```

The `LoginForm` in the case of an attempt to authenticate - should call a function `Auth(Login, Password)` of the controller, which in case of successful authorization, will change store and fill SessionId.

Is it a good idea if the link to the `Auth` function in the Redux.Store?
If not - how can pass a link to the `Auth` function to the LoginForm component?

Answer (score 0):

The `Auth` function is a side effect in your app. Has nothing to do with redux. In order to handle side async side effects you have to use something like redux-thunk or redux-saga.

Comment: I wanted to say that LoginForm should not do Ajax. LoginForm should call the handler when the user enters login and password. But where does the handler come from?
Can pass it to the LoginForm  as a props in jsx. But if there are Redux, why not mapping storage in the LoginForm.props and saving the handler in the Redux.Store?

Comment: The handler should be actually a Redux action. Connect the form to Redux and use mapDispatchToProps to pass the action creator. That is I believe the correct way. After that you’ll hit another problem - who waits for this action and trigger the Auth function? This is where redux-thunk and redux-saga comes to play.